# saving model output from Decision tree train classifier as a text file in Spark Scala platform

Tags: scala, apache-spark, decision-tree

The codes I was using to train the decision tree are as follows:

```
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext 
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.DecisionTree      
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint   
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors  
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.configuration.Algo._  
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.impurity.Gini   
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils   
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics
```

// Load and parse the data file

```
    val data = sc.textFile("data/mllib/spt.csv")
    val parsedData = data.map { line =>
    val parts = line.split(',').map(_.toDouble)
    LabeledPoint(parts(0), Vectors.dense(parts.tail))
}
```

//Split the data

```
    val splits = parsedData.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))
    val (trainingData, testData) = (splits(0), splits(1))
```

// Train a DecisionTree model.
// Empty categoricalFeaturesInfo indicates all features are continuous.

```
    val numClasses = 2
    val categoricalFeaturesInfo = Map[Int, Int]()
    val impurity = "gini"
    val maxDepth = 5
    val maxBins = 32

    val model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(trainingData, numClasses,     categoricalFeaturesInfo,
    impurity, maxDepth, maxBins)


    val labelAndPreds = trainingData.map { point =>
    val prediction = model.predict(point.features)
(point.label, prediction)
     }

//Training error       
    val trainErr = labelAndPreds.filter(r => r._1 != r._2).count.toDouble /     trainingData.count
    println("Training Error = " + trainErr)

//Model Output                 
    println("Learned classification tree model:\n" + model)

    println("Learned classification tree model:\n" + model.toDebugString)
```

I want "model.toDebugString" to write or output as a text file. I found a lot of answers similar to this question, but not specific. It would be of great help if a specific help or cue can be provided. Since I am new to SCALA I am facing issues with the proper libraries to include.

I tried with the code below:

```
    modelFile = ~/decisionTreeModel.txt"
    f = open(modelFile,"w") 
    f.write(model.toDebugString())
    f.close()
```

but it was giving me this error:

```
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but '.' found.
       modelFile = ~/decisionTreeModel.txt"
                                      ^
<console>:1: error: unclosed string literal
       modelFile = ~/decisionTreeModel.txt"
                                           ^
```

Also, tried to save the model:

```
// Save and load model
    model.save(sc, "myModelPath")
    val sameModel = DecisionTreeModel.load(sc, "myModelPath")
```

The above code was also throwing errors.Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Partha, did you see that there is a leading quotation mark missing when assigning to modelFile?

Comment: Yes I tried by putting it but still throwing errors

Answer (score 0):

Try this (for example on the shell):

```
snow:~ mkamp$ spark-shell 

...

scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:15

scala> new java.io.PrintWriter("/tmp/decisionTreeModel.txt") { writeln(rdd.toDebugString); close }
res0: java.io.PrintWriter = $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anon$1@65fc2639
```

Then on the command line (outside of Spark).

```
snow:~ mkamp$ cat /tmp/decisionTreeModel.txt 
(4) ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:15 []
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Mariano. I tried your suggestion, but it is still throwing errors. I am pasting below the errors I am getting.

Comment: <console>:38: error: not found: type PrintWriter
              new PrintWriter("~/decisionTreeModel.txt") { write(model.toDebugSt
ring()); close }
                  ^
<console>:38: error: not found: value write
              new PrintWriter("~/decisionTreeModel.txt") { write(model.toDebugSt
ring()); close }
                                                           ^
<console>:38: error: not found: value close
              new PrintWriter("~/decisionTreeModel.txt") { write(model.toDebugSt
ring()); close }

         ^

Comment: Sorry, I was too short. You need to import PrintWriter. See if above addition works.

Comment: I tried that also and included the library but the output is like this:    <console>:60: error: not enough arguments for method apply: (index: Int)Char in
class StringOps.
Unspecified value parameter index.
              new PrintWriter("~/decisionTreeModel.txt") { write(model.toDebugSt
ring()); close }

    ^