# Precision, Recall, Accuracy calculation for Decision Tree in SCALA Spark Environment

Tags: apache-spark, decision-tree, precision-recall

I am trying to calculate Precision, Recall, Accuracy for decision tree. This is in relation to a previous question about the same program although the context was different. Please find the link to see the all the codes:
 [saving model output from Decision tree train classifier as a text file in Spark Scala platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33183857/saving-model-output-from-decision-tree-train-classifier-as-a-text-file-in-spark)

The codes for calculation are:

```
//Precision, Recall, Confusion Matrix 
val evaluationMetrics = new MulticlassMetrics(labelAndPreds.map(x => (x._1, x._2)))
evaluationMetrics.precision

evaluationMetrics.recall

evaluationMetrics.confusionMatrix
```

Precision=98.52% and Recall= 98.52%, which seems unlikely since,

```
Confusion Matrix
    Predicted
Actual  0   1   
0   16877   251 
1   2       20
```

The above is the Spark calculation of the Confusion Matrix.

The arrangement,

```
Predicted
Actual  0   1
    0   TN  FN
    1   FP  TP
```

So, Precision = TP/(TP+FP)=20/(20+2) =0.9091
Recall = TP/(TP+FN) = 20/(20+251) =0.074.

Please correct me if I am wrong. If I consider (0,0) group as True Positives(TP) then also Precision and Recall will not be the same. But Spark out as per the code above is showing the same.

It would be great to have suggestions and help. Thanks in advance.

I would like to know how to calculate precision , recall and accuracy from the confusion matrix that I can convert to string.

Comment: TN(0,0)=16877, TP(1,1)= 20, FP(1,0)=2 and FN(0,1)=251, read as(Actual, Predicted)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Calculate precision and recall from confusion matrix. I have edited the actual question too. Is there a way I can calculate it from the confusion matrix directly?

Comment: I am actually finding difficulty to use the individual elements of the confusion matrix to calculate precision or recall